# QGIS OSM display issue

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins

I discovered that Open Street Map in QGIS would not print properly because the street names were illegible. I looked through some questions that others had posted and saw that I needed to install the Tile Map Scale plug-in, but afterwards I still wasn't able to print and see the names of the streets at any scale. Can anyone tell me how to properly use this plug-in so that I can read the names of streets in OSM?

Comment: Same here: Open Street Map returns maps with illegible font, see image compared with google maps: https://imgur.com/a/luh6r